# How can you disable all anchors when there is no internet connection?

Tags: javascript

I'm checking ~every 5 seconds to see if Im online, and if I'm not , then I want to disable all   links.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

setInterval(function(){
 var status = navigator.onLine ? 'enabled-link' : 'disabled-link';/* check whether online */
 document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML = status /* display 'anchor' somewhere */
 if(status == 'disabled-link';) {     
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].onclick = function() {return(false);};
                                          };    
                                }
                      }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: I can't get this to work!

Comment: Read up on [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What was the problem?

You were had a semi-colon in your `if` statement, and that was causing the problem. I also prefer using e.preventDefault() to stop the normal functioning of the hyperlink. I am not sure whether simply returning false will work.

#### The solution:

Please Try this code instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple async sync example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="anchor"></p>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        
    </body>
    <script>
        setInterval(function(){
            var status = navigator.onLine ? 'enabled-link' : 'disabled-link';/* check whether online */
            document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML = status; /* display 'anchor' somewhere */
        
            if(status ==  'disabled-link') {
                var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
                    anchors[i].onclick = function(e) {e.preventDefault();};
                };
            }
        }, 400);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: BKSpurgeon - That works! Can e.preventDefault be unbound when the connection returns?

Comment: @EPH you might have to set up a separate handler event handler to re-enable all the hyperlinks when the connection returns. But that would be a different stack overflow question. you may be relatively new to stack overflow - if the answer is satisfactory, then the etiquette is to "upvote" the answer, and if you think it the best of all the submitted answers, to "mark as accepted".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events you can add handlers when it goes on and off line instead of polling every 5 seconds, and you can simply enable/disable links accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try write a fn to detect if the browser has internet or not using the following code

```
function isOnline() { 
    return ( navigator.onLine) 
}
```

this will be a boolean value so you can simply write if/else statement and add/remove css class

```
.isDisabled {
  color: currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The OP is using `navigator.onLine` in their code already. The CSS given will not disable the link at all.

Comment: the css is to make the a tag look like disable by removing the cursor, however there can be a better way to make the a tag look disabled